# changing a variable in a string javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string looking like: some+thing+-+More

How do i replace the + sign?

I have tried the following without success:

```
temps = "some+thing+-+More";
temps = temps.replace("/+" /g, "blank");
temps = temps.replace("+" /g, "blank");
temps = temps.replace(/+/g, "blank");
```

Comment: A character set will do it: `/[+]/g` or you can just escape it: `/\+/g`.

Comment: Note that `"/+"` actually has a different meaning - namely just these two characters. The escape character in JavaScript is ``\``.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to escape the plus sign with a backslash, like so:

```
var temps ="some+thing+-+More";
temps = temps.replace(/\+/g, "blank");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"+ + + +".replace(/\+/g, "blank")
```

This results:

```
"blank blank blank blank"
```

You should use the escape char:

```
temps = temps.replace(/\+/g, "blank");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
temps = temps.replace(/\+/g, "blank");
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/M6T8g/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jonathan.

I took a different approach: I figure out the Hex number for + sign was 2B So....

```
temps = temps = temps.replace(/\x2B/g, "blank");
```

also did the trick!

Comment: This is actually a really good technique for lots of other situations. \x for the hex value and \u for unicode. For the OP's case it is a bit overkill but most developers should be aware of this none the less.